# Linkchecker and revision

Tags: nodes, navigation

I am using linkchecker and revisioning modules on a website with plenty of redirects.
At the moment when linkchecker detects a redirect, it changes the link in the body field...This creates a new revision, which is not published.

Can I influence the behaviour somehow and whenever linkchecker creates a revision, to publish the revision.

EDIT: 
Sample logic ?:

1. Add new user "linkchecker"
2. Under Linkchecker configuration,impersonate Linkchecker with this user.
3. Delete all of the current unpublished revisions, after that run the linkchecker from cron, it will create new unpublished revisions with user Linkchecker
4. Programmatically change to that revision all of the nodes that have revisions from "linkchecker user"

Best regards.

Oleg

Comment: Yes, you can patch it or hack it for that effect. Yes, you can set up script that will auto-publish linkchecker revisions. But we don't know what (if any) modules interfere with your revisioning (revision moderation changes a lot, for example) so we cannot tell exactly how. Also, it seems that module's maintainer is pretty active in issue queue, so consider giving him all info needed in a bugreport or feature request.

Comment: There are no other modules that can interfere as far as I know. Revision moderation is not installed.

@Mołot, can you tell me if I am correct in the script logic.....updating the description of the question

Comment: Seems logic you described should be doable with Rules. That's about how I would approach this issue.